# humanoid.health is always at 100 but its actually not 100

Tags: lua, roblox

so im trying to make a roblox game, and im trying to detect when the npc's health is at 0 itll stop shooting, but it always is at 100, please help

```
me = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
function touched(hit)
    if me.Health > 0 then
        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= nil then
            script.Parent.Parent.shoot.Shotgun:Play()
            script.Parent.Parent.shoot.Transparency = 0;
            script.Parent.Parent.shoot.CanTouch = true;
            wait(0.2)
            script.Parent.Parent.shoot.Transparency = 1;
            script.Parent.Parent.shoot.CanTouch = false;
            wait(0.05)
            script.Parent.Position += Vector3.new(0,200,0)
            wait(0)
            script.Parent.Position -= Vector3.new(0,200,0)
        end
    end
end

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(touched)
```

Comment: Check that you are actually dealing damage to the NPC. And If this is a server script, make sure whatever weapon you are using is dealing damage ServerSide, not ClientSide. If you are confused, I suggest you read about [FilteringEnabled](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Workspace/FilteringEnabled)

Comment: i shoot the npc and it shows the health going down